# difference between preventDefault() and off('click')

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I use `on()` JQuery function and `preventDefault()` for prevent anchor default action. I can not understand `off()` JQuery function. can I use `off('click')` instead of:

```
$('.anchor').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

I mean, can I use this for prevent default action of anchor?

```
$('.anchor').off('click');
```

Comment: `off` disable `click` event handlers that you add. `on` add new event handler where you can prevent default event (link don't opened for example in href)

Comment: This is self explanatory if you read the documentation on off and preventDefault

Answer (score 2):

No, as per the documentation of [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

> The `.off()` method removes event handlers that were attached with `.on()`.

So `off()` only removes handlers that were added by jQuery. But default handlers, e.g. on a link or on a submit button, must be prevented by `preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 1):

off : disable the eventHandler so no function can be execute on click
preventdefault : disable the default eventHandler but you can use your own function.

Answer (score 1):

They are logically very different.

`preventDefault()` stops the browser from acting on the event behaviour but still executes the JS code. For example, in the below, the URL the `.anchor` element points to will not be transferred, however the JS code will still run:

```
$('.anchor').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('the browser wont redirect, but you will see this line in the console')
});
```

On the other hand, `off()` completely removes any event handler of the given type from the element. In this case, the browser will be transferred to the given URL on click and no JS code will be run.

```
$('.anchor').off('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

[**off**](http://api.jquery.com/off/) will remove an event handler which was previously attached to it.

But it will not stop the default behaviour of the element

You can add multiple event to a single selector.

For example

```
$('somElem').on('click',function(){
   // rest of code
})

$('somElem').on('someOtherEvent',function(){
   // rest of code
})
```

So before `someOtherEvent` is triggered it will remove any other event that is attached to the element.

Comment: *tag* does not mean the same as *element*. The latter is correct in this context.